# XML to HTML table with XSLT with dynamic headings

Tags: xslt

My question is a bit similar to [XML to HTML table with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657549/xml-to-html-table-with-xslt) .

I have a dictionary defined as follows in XML:

```
<dictionary>
    <languages>
        <language>en</language>
        <language>ja</language>
    </languages>
    <entries>
        <entry id="1">
            <en>Test</en>
            <ja>テスト</ja>
        </entry>
        <entry id="2">
            <en>Test2</en>
            <ja>テスト2</en>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</dictionary>
```

And I would like the following output in XHTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>en</th>
            <th>ja</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>テスト</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>テスト2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I adapted the answer from [XML to HTML table with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657549/xml-to-html-table-with-xslt) as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="//dictionary/entries">
     <table><xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/></table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry[1]">
  <thead><tr><xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="header"/></tr></thead>
  <xsl:call-template name="standardRow"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry" name="standardRow">
  <tbody><tr><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></tr></tbody>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry/*">
  <td><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry/*" mode="header">
  <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The thing is that I might have inputs as follows:

```
<dictionary>
    <languages>
        <language>en</language>
        <language>ja</language>
            <language>id</language>
    </languages>
    <entries>
        <entry id="1">
            <en>Test</en>
            <ja>テスト</ja>
        </entry>
        <entry id="2">
            <ja>テスト2</ja>
            <en>Test2</en>
            <id>uji2</id>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</dictionary>
```

As you might have understood, XSLT takes the first `entry` node to define the column names and the column `id` is not generated. Moreover, if the language order is changed in `entry` the `<td>` do not appear in order.

With the input above, I would like the following output:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>en</th>
            <th>ja</th>
            <th>id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>テスト</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>テスト2</td>
            <td>Uji2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my first time using XSLT and I do not really know how I could do this. I guess I could use the `languages` node. Please note that the XML input format is flexible and I would welcome any suggestions even if I need to change the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="entry/*" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-name())"/>

  <xsl:variable name="languages" select="/dictionary/languages/language"/>

  <xsl:template match="dictionary">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="entries"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entries">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$languages" mode="header"/>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="language" mode="header">
    <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$languages">
        <xsl:with-param name="entry" select="current()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="language">
    <xsl:param name="entry"/>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', concat(generate-id($entry), '|', .))"/>      
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I ran tests with this stylesheet and it looks that it works perfectly. Answer accepted! Thank you very much. The key is in `variable` and `key` and I did not how to use them.

Comment: The key to the solution is making to sure to process `$languages` each time you want to output the data for an `entry` and then passing in the `entry` as a parameter. The use of `xsl:key` and of the `key` function is there for efficiency, you could also use `<xsl:value-of select="$entry/*[local-name() = current()]"/>` instead of the `<xsl:value-of select="key('k1', concat(generate-id($entry), '|', .))"/>`.