# XML file code to display in wpf web browser on application

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listbox, browser

At the moment I have items that are in a Listbox and can be changed and edited. When I click on a button the items in the Listbox get saved to a XML file on my computer, and a window will appear with the a Web Browser object on the Window which I want the items from the file to be displayed.

At the moment this is my code for when I click a button:

```
try
{
    string selectedStandard = (string)cmbStandard.SelectedItem;
    Information info = new Information();
    info.Standards = _standardDefinitions;
    SaveXML.SaveData(info, string.Format("{0}.xml",selectedStandard));

    HTMLBrowser boss = new HTMLBrowser(selectedStandard);
    boss.Show();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

This is my SaveXML Class:

```
public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
{
   XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
   TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
   sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
   writer.Close();
}
```

This is the class I created which contains a property I save all the things from  the Listbox to:

```
private List<StandardDefinition> standards;

public List<StandardDefinition> Standards
{
    get { return standards; }
    set { standards = value; }
}
```

Then on my other form I tried to display the list of items in the Browser using this code:

```
wb.NavigateToStream(System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\user1\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AddingColumn\AddingColumn\bin\Debug\data.xml"));
```

This seems to display the code that was saved in the file and not the list in the box.

This is what is displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Information xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<Standards>


-<StandardDefinition>

<Column_Name>P101</Column_Name>

<Question>true</Question>

<Autofail>false</Autofail>

</StandardDefinition>


-<StandardDefinition>

<Column_Name>P101</Column_Name>

<Question>Hello</Question>

 <Autofail>false</Autofail>

</StandardDefinition>


-<StandardDefinition>

<Column_Name>P101</Column_Name>

< Question>1</Question>

<Autofail>false</Autofail>

</StandardDefinition>


-<StandardDefinition>

<Column_Name>P11</Column_Name>

<Question>well no</Question>

<Autofail>false</Autofail>

</StandardDefinition>

</Standards>
</Information>
```

This is what it should display LIKE:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt2mE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser after discovering that file is xml converts it into html that can be interacted with. You can see html by right click and selecting `View Source` pop up menu. You need to do similar and convert you xml into html in way you like to be shown. There are many ways of doing that, for example by applying xslt transformation as it shown in [XML to HTML table with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657549/xml-to-html-table-with-xslt)